# MediaScannerConnection.scanFile can't get mp3 album art

Tags: android

After using mp3agic to change mp3 album art, scan new mp3 file and can't get changed album art,
mp3agic change album art code

```
mp3file = new Mp3File(edit_song.getPath());
ID3v24Tag id3v24Tag = new ID3v24Tag();

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pick_image_file);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte [] bytes=byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
Log.e("image bytes length",bytes.length+"");
id3v24Tag.setAlbumImage(bytes, "image/jpg");

mp3file.setId3v2Tag(id3v24Tag);

edit_song_file = new File(edit_song.getPath());
temp_file = new File(edit_song_file.getParent()+"/temp_file.mp3");

mp3file.save(temp_file.getPath());
```

scan new file code

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[] { temp_file.getPath() }, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.e("scan completed","true");
                    }
                });
```

Changing album art is fine, but scan the new file and system can't generate data in provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is old file info still exists in the provider, so if want to update info, you have to delete these old info.